# How do I add a bunch of JPanels to my JFrame using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I generate a bunch of JPanels and then pass them into a class that extends JFrame.  How do I add an indefinite number of JPanels to this JFrame.  I was also reading about JScrollPane should I incorporate this somehow into the design?

Example Code:

```
class foo extends JPanel
{
  //generate JPanels
}

class bar extends JFrame
{
  //grab some amount of foo classes and put them into this JFrame and show it
}
```

Also is there anything I need to watch out for when showing this JFrame?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I add an indefinite number of JPanels to this JFrame?

`CardLayout`, `JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame`, `JTabbedPane`, `JScrollPane` - there are a number of options.

> Also is there anything I need to watch out for when showing this JFrame?

(shrugs)

- Construct and show GUI components on the EDT.
- `pack()` the GUI before setting the position and calling `setVisible(true)`.
- Don't rely on the default layouts of content panes.
- Don't implement custom painting in a top level container.
- ..

Answer (score 3):

[JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)  -> [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) -> fathers [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) then you'll decide which of [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) will lay your `bunch of JPanels`, by defalut [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), don't forget to play with PreferedSize for childsPanels