# JButton Form within Click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

is it possible when I click a `JButton` in my Java UI they'll be another `JFrame` that pops out and it includes other Forms or other layout? for example, I click the "View Employee" button they'll be another form that's going to pop out but it contains the employee information on another window?

Comment: Generally an application would have only one `JFrame`, use `JDialog` instances for pop-ups, but also investigate the plethora of possibilities for including more than one collection of controls in one (top level) GUI.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037573/how-do-i-add-a-bunch-of-jpanels-to-my-jframe-using-java-swing/6037667#6037667).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better would be implemnts [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) rather than to create a new [Top-Level Container(s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: +1 agree, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843).

Comment: yes Java Swing default http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html , because these Containers stay in the mamory untill current JVM instance exists, sure there is possible create a new Container, then not JFrame (too hard manage actions betweens two JFrames) but JDialog and re-use that for another actions, to avoiding create a new Container on Fly

Comment: I was thinking of showing an EmployeeProfile, will the JDialog suffice that?

Comment: if you want any form of popup window then JDialog is best way how to do it, for exclusive window you have to look for setModal/ModalityTypes, if you want to re-use this JDialog the don't forget to set `my&Dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: how about for logging in? Since I am creating a payroll system, and I need a log in button, then it will bring the user to another form? is that possible?

Comment: yes you'll create JDialog, if loggin passed then you'll create the aplication JFrame